# RowFilter with Scan Query in the HBase

Tags: hbase

I have following table in the HBase;

```
---row---                       ---columns---
15678,ctx,plm,1561356310000         etc...
15678,ctx,plm,1561388710000         etc...
15678,ctx,plm,1561476430000         etc...
26355,yt,rcc,1561356310000          etc...
26355,yt,rcc,1561356310000          etc...
...                                 ...
```

---

My `rowKey` format is;

```
<id_of_device>,<id_of_component>,<id_of_item>,<timestamp>
```

And, I received an unexpected query request. I must get all values of the specific **device(id_of_device)** between specific **start time and end time (timestamps in the row)**.

---

**For example;**
I want to get data of device `15678` between `startTime(1561356310000)` and `endTime(1561476430000)`. How can I prepare scan query for this? According to my rowKey design, I write `"id_of_component" and "id_of_item"`. But I want to get data using only `"id_of_device" and "start and end timestamps"`.

```
scan 'mytable', {STARTROW => '15678,..,..,1561356310000', ENDROW => '15678,..,..,1561476430000'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your row key design; you can use a RowFilter with regex alongside start and stop rows.

```
scan 'mytable', {STARTROW => '15678', ENDROW => '15679', FILTER => "RowFilter(=, 'regexstring:1561356310000$')"}
```

would get data at exact time of 1561356310000. If you create your timestamp regex according to your date range, you can query a time range.

```
scan 'mytable', {STARTROW => '15678', ENDROW => '15679', FILTER => "RowFilter(=, 'regexstring:15613563.....$')"}
```

would get 100 seconds of data between timestamps 1561356300000 and 1561356399999

```
scan 'mytable', {STARTROW => '15678', ENDROW => '15679', FILTER => "RowFilter(=, 'regexstring:1561356[3|4|5].....$')"}
```

would get 300 seconds of data between timestamps 1561356300000 and 1561356599999

Using regex filters may not be very efficient but `id_of_component,id_of_item` data in the middle of your row key blocks the ability to scan with ranges.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I don't find regexstring for this problem? How can I do this? For example is that true? 15678,(.*),15622[1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9].......$

Comment: Getting an exact number range with regular expressions may be very complicated. You can do it but you will need a very long regex. Which might also result in poor performance. In your example, you metioned 33 hours of data. You can narrow results to an enclosing range (like 100K seconds: 27 hours ) and then process your result.

Comment: In your case it would be sth like 
1561(3563[1-9]|356[4-9].|35[7-9]..|3[6-9]...|4764[0-2]|476[0-3].|47[0-5]..|4[0-6]...)....$ but try not to use it. Narrowing to an enclosing result with regex and then processing the result to match your exact range would be a much better approach if that's an option.